# Exporting CSV's from SQL Server - Iterating different Key

Tags: sql-server, csv, export, bulk

I am currently going through the process of exporting a CSV file from an SQL Server DB for each unique key in a database that contains meter readings. I am doing this one at a time manually via Export data in SSMS.... It is making me want to die since I have 200 unique key values.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DataTime, DataValue
FROM [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue]
WHERE PointID = 68352
```

The bulk of the query stays the same, the only value i change is the PointID. I need tab separated CSV's as output where the filename = the PointID.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `loop` and a temp table to accomplish this.

```
declare @i int = (select count(distinct PointID) from [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue])
select row_number() over(order by PointID) as rn, * 
into #tmp --temp table
from [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue]
declare @id int
declare @sql varchar(4000)
while @i > 0
begin
set @id = (select PointID from #tmp where rn = @i)
SELECT DataTime, DataValue
FROM [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue]
WHERE PointID = @id;
select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT DataTime, DataValue FROM [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue] WHERE PointID = '+str(@id)+'" queryout "C:\Temp\'+str(@id)+'+'.csv'+'" -S servername -d databasename -U username -P password'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
set @i = @i-1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see where you are creating CSV's?

Comment: modified it. replace the `servername`, `folderpath`,  `username`, `password` fields for your database.

Comment: I get an error which looks like its printing out the syntax options for BCP in the results window.

Comment: modified,it should be an issue with the quotes in `bcp` command. Play around with it until you get it right.

Comment: It still doesn't work and unfortunateley I have no idea about the structure of a bcp statement.

Comment: post your `bcp` statement to show the modifications you've done

Comment: Ive only tried changing some of your quotes, but still get the full syntax options in the results pane

Comment: quotes don't require a change. you should provide values for `servername`, `databasename`,`username` and `password`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xp_cmdshell and bcp to achieve what you want but it requires more privileges, in case you're thinking about running this in production.

You need to configure enable advanced options in order to enable xp_cmdshell and then enable xp_cmdshell

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 RECONFIGURE
```

Then we gather all PointIDs into a cursor so we can process individually

```
Declare curPointIDS Cursor For 
    Select Distinct PointID From [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue]
Open curPointIDS

Declare @pointId Int, @cmd Varchar(max)
Fetch Next From curPointIDS Into @pointId

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
Begin
    Set @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT DataTime, DataValue FROM [i96X].[dbo].[PointValue] '
        + 'WHERE PointID = ' + LTRIM(@pointId) + '" queryout '
        + '"C:\Temp\Results_' + LTRIM(@pointId) + '.csv" -T -c -t,'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
End

Close curPointIDS
Deallocate curPointIDS
```

**xp_cdshell:** Runs commands in command prompt (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

**bcp:** Sql Server's data extract utility https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

**Parameters:**

-T: Use trusted connection

-c: Data type will be characters

-t: Specify delimiter, in this case it's comma (,)

Comment: So your example code there, run that in a standard SQL query window within SSMS?

Comment: Ok, so your code appeared to work, but the timestamp was not returning the full value as stored in the table. Also, it appeared to be extremely slow?

Comment: @tomstephens89 it should be slow since it's running in a cursor and you should adjust your query to output the desired string format for your timestamp column.

Comment: Ok, but how do I specify a tab for delimiter instead of a comma?

Comment: @tomstephens89 you just change the -t, to anything you want as a delimiter, -t is the parameter for delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fix list of meters you can create a batch file and extract this information, on a regular basis, using the Task Scheduler.

Basically you should put on this batch file one row for each meter you want to extract and use **sqlcmd** to extract the historical records.

For example, let's say you want to extract the historical data for the pointIDs (1, 2, 3). You can create a batch file called "extract.bat" with the following lines:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select * from i96x.dbo.PointValue where Pointid=1" -s "\t" -o "C:\Results\1.csv"  
sqlcmd -Q "select * from i96x.dbo.PointValue where Pointid=2" -s "\t" -o "C:\Results\2.csv"  
sqlcmd -Q "select * from i96x.dbo.PointValue where Pointid=3" -s "\t" -o "C:\Results\3.csv"
```

You just need to run this batch file and get your files. This files will use **tab** as a column separator. If you want to use comma as column separator just change **-s ,** on each row.

You can use excel to make easier to generate this batch file.

Another head up, with that query you will get **ALL** the values for each pointid. If you are working with meter probably you will be interested in extract only the last month. To do that you will need to adjust the query.